# How to make field text bold in custom edit form?

Tags: custom-form, spfield, formatting

I am already using custom field iterators to customize the fields on my list forms.
When users are creating or editing a list item, I want certain field names to show in **bold**.

For example, when users are creating a new Task item, I want the fields **Assigned To** and **Description** to be in bold.

How can I achieve this and I am not interested in using InfoPath for the forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery to find the fields and apply css to them with something like:

```
$("h3[class^='ms-standardheader']:contains('Assigned To')").css("font-weight", "Bold");
$("h3[class^='ms-standardheader']:contains('Description')").css("font-weight", "Bold");
```

Comment: You're welcome.  If it's a custom form you created in SharePoint Designer, you can always apply styling directly in code/design/split view as well.